# Radius of convergence of random power series

Tags: probability, power-series

Given a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|) < \infty$ and the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n z^n$$
In previous exercises I have shown that the radius of convergence is almost surely constant (using Kolmogorov 0-1 law). But now I am struggeling to determine the radius of convergence, because there is no specific distribution given.

Do you have any hints for me?
Thanks!

Comment: Consider what a radius of convergence $\neq 1$ would imply for the coefficients.

Comment: $r =\frac{1}{ \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}   \sqrt[n]{|X_n|}}$. If $r \neq 1$, then $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}   \sqrt[n]{|X_n|} \neq 1$. From calculus lectures I know that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{ \sqrt[n]{|a|}} = 1$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$. So if the limit of $\sqrt[n]{|X_n|}$ exists, then it would be a contradiction?

Comment: you can even do with less: requiring $E[log^{+}(|X|)]<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|\lt 1$, then 
$$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=1}^N \left|X_n\right| \left|z\right|^n  \right] = \mathbb E\left[ \left|X_1\right|\right]\sum_{n=1}^N \left|z\right|^n\leqslant  \mathbb E\left[ \left|X_1\right|\right]\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|z\right|^n$$
and by monotone convergence, the random variable $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|X_n\right| \left|z\right|^n$ has a finite expectation, hence is finite almost everywhere. Consequently, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n z^n$ converges almost everywhere. The radius of convergence is thus bigger or equal to $1$.

Now, let $r\gt 1$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|X_n\right| r^n$ 
cannot be convergent (unless $X_n=0$ a.s.): by the $0$-$1$ law, it should be almost everywhere convergent, hence $\left|X_n\right| r^n\to 0$ almost surely, hence in probability hence $\mathbb P\left\{\left|X_1\right|\gt r^{-n}\right\}\to 0$ which entails $\mathbb P\left\{\left|X_1\right|\gt 0\right\}=0$.

In conclusion: if $X_1=0$ a.s., the radius of convergence is almost surely infinite, otherwise, it is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. But I don't understand the last line of your proof. You have only shown that if $|z|<1$ then the radius of convergence is bigger or equal to 1, and in the other case, if $X_1 = 0$ a.s., the radius of convergence is almost surely infinite. How do you conclude that it is 1 otherwise?

Comment: If $|z|\gt 1$ and $X_1\neq 0$, the series doesn't converge.

Comment: Actually I don't even think you need to look at r>1 here, just look at r=1. So you are asking whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges, which would require $X_n \to 0$ a.s. But this does not happen, for instance by Borel-Cantelli applied to the events $\{X_n > \epsilon\}$ for small enough $\epsilon$.